# MySQL aggregation count performance

Tags: mysql, performance, aggregate, count, query-performance

I have a table with about 30 million records, and I'm doing a query where I can group by field *Year* and count the results for that year.

The table structure looks like:

```
id | year | amount
```

The query I'm currently executing is:

```
SELECT year, count(year) FROM mytable GROUP BY year
```

This works just fine and gives me the results I expect.

The issue is that this these queries are being done as part of a web application and they currently take about 6-7 seconds to execute. I have an index on the `year` field (and on `amount`). I don't think I can pre-compute summary statistics because the query can have arbitrary where clauses added to it, e.g.

```
SELECT year, count(year) FROM mytable WHERE amount > 500 GROUP BY year
```

Though I could pre-compute the query in the case when there are no additional `WHERE` clauses.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the computation of the `count` part of the query? That seems to be where the slowdown is.

Comment: You should have a combined index on (amount,year) for those WHERE queries.

Comment: Right, but in the case where there is no where clause, it's still 6-7 seconds.

Comment: How big is the table?  What Engine are you using?  Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE.  If year is NOT NULL, you could use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(year).

Comment: The table has 30 million rows. Engine is InnoDB. Using `COUNT(*)` yields similar results. The create table statement is `CREATE TABLE mytable(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,Year int NOT NULL,Amount DOUBLE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));`

Comment: I would add an index on `(year, amount)`. It should speed up the query without `WHERE` and probably the other one you have showed us.

Comment: I tried pruning the table to just the `id` and `year` columns and have an index on `year`. Performance didn't improve though.